# Home made captcha , is it safe?

Tags: php, security, captcha, brute-force

I've been gathering information about how to protect from *brut force attack* on the logging page or from the haressment of *multiple account creation.*

I came to the conclusion (thanks to you guys of Stackoverflow)  that the best way would be to use captchas.

But uneasy to read captchas or accented characters may deter users from using a website.

So, I found out an easy to use little script I adapted to my site. It's a simple math captcha proposing to sum up 2 figures from *zero to ten*. It displays the words **'one' 'two' 'three'** ... not the figures.

My questions are :

1) Does this little captcha provide sufficient security in itself ?

2) Is the way I integrated it safe ? ( any way to bypass it ?)

*To avoid pasting 800 lines of code I've made a summary, I hope it is clear.*

**captcha script :**

```
$n1  = mt_rand(0,10);  
$n2  = mt_rand(0,10);  
$fig = array('zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten');  
$result = $n1 + $n2;
$sentence = $fig[$n1] .' plus '.$fig[$n2];  
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $result;  
$captcha_label = "<label for='captcha' >How much does ".$sentence."make?</label>";               
echo $captcha_label."</label><input  type='text' name='captcha'  value=''/><br />";                                 
echo "<input type='submit' name='create' value='create account'>";
```

**PAGES:**

- **form.php:**

all *'create account'* input fields + captcha

=> test

- **test.php:**

  `if($_POST['captcha'] != $_SESSION['captcha']){

      $_SESSION['captcha_control'] = "false";`
      }

Then all *'create account'* $_POSTS are injection tested

If any of them or the captcha returns "false" , the script deflects to => problem.php

- **problem.php:**

Echoes the initial form with all "wrong fields" highlighted 
and a new captcha is displayed, was it right or was it wrong.
validation => back to **test.php**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it worth the time and effort to do this?

Comment: Re-inventing the wheel is always a bad idea.

Comment: Captchas should easily be solvable by humans, but not so much by computers. Your captcha will deter most spammers because it's a home-made solution, but if someone wanted to, they could crack it in an hour or so. I'd just stick to reCAPTHCA.

Comment: And what is the best wheel so far ?

Comment: @SunnyOne: http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: With regards to `Is the way I integrated it safe ?`, if you're just creating the words "one", "two", "three", etc. dynamically, and they look the same every time, it would be trivial to create a script that recognized these images, parsed the image you gave, and then came up with a solution. I would reccomend [recaptcha](http://recaptcha.net) which is for some reason down right now.

Comment: ReCAPTCHA is actually worse in some ways, because tools to solve it (which use human effort on the back end) are widely available and are in use by spammers. Forms using ReCAPTCHA **do** receive spam submissions.

Comment: @duskwuff Any spam system that uses human effort on the backend will render a captcha system useless.

Comment: @Vulcan: Not entirely. Almost [all](http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/user/login) of them work on images. If your captcha isn't image-based, most of those services are rendered useless.

Comment: Life is so strange :-) My poor little captcha is not worth spending time on it. And the best captcha is worse in some way, in fact, and is down for some reason reason right now ... good summary ?

Comment: @Zar: **[Please read](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/08/reinvent-wheel.html)**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like most simple CAPTCHAs, it will work reasonably well until your site is significant enough for a spammer to spend a few minutes figuring out how to break it. At that point, you will be inundated by spam.

If you intend to use your own CAPTCHA, this is overkill -- it doesn't even need to be random. Simply requesting users to enter a constant word (e.g, "Type 'orange' into this box") will stop the vast majority of simple spambots.

Comment: However, if a spambot is customized to break through your system, it will take mere seconds to program it to complete such a simple captcha.  The addition one in the question would take slightly longer, but still wouldn't take any experienced programmer fewer than a couple minutes.

Comment: If you're a valuable enough target, it'll probably be broken or brute-forced no matter what. Same goes if the CAPTCHA you're using is found in common software. Spammers ruin everything. :(

Comment: Thanks. Back to Recaptcha then ?

Comment: Nope, as I mentioned, that's worse. Since reCaptcha is frequently encountered, many pieces of commonly used spam software will recognize it and pass it off to human solvers automatically. You are actually better off starting out with your own custom CAPTCHA.

Comment: I honestly don't know why someone would even make a run at this path. The time it takes to type the question above is more than it takes to integrate with reCAPTCHA.

Comment: Again, **reCAPTCHA is not all that effective**, largely due to its popularity. It's algorithmically strong, but is easily recognized and passed off to human solvers. Forms using it will receive spam that would be blocked by a custom confirmation question.

Comment: @duskwuff Would the idea of a mini animated GIF a good track ? ( For instance showing randomly a fruit or an animal popping out of a magma of colors and forms for a second and triggered with JS). Would it be more difficult to break or is it overkill too as you previously said? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think duskwuff answered your question about the quality of your captcha.  As to whether it is "safe" as asked in the question title, you haven't defined that term but probably not.

```
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $result;
```

probably allocates a server-side session before you have determined whether you're dealing with a legitimate user.  This can open you up to DOS attack since an attacker only needs to create a large number of unique sessions within the session timeout window to eat up storage on your server.  Since you're relying on obscurity, storing the answer in a hidden variable (and putting all the inputs inside a `<form>` tag) would do just as well without occupying server-side resources.

Comment: +1 thanks for your insight. The only solution Recaptcha then ?

Comment: @SunnyOne, If you're worried about users being deterred, then I think a system like Recaptcha that has done a lot of work to handle visually-impaired users, non English speakers, etc. would likely be more accessible than a one-off.  The best way to avoid deterring users is to have compelling content available outside your user-signup wall.  Btw, captchas will not prevent "multiple account creation" just keep it down to low levels.  Someone willing to pay low-wage workers in a third-world country can still employ people to create accounts.

Comment: Maybe forgot to mention: my site is not forum-like, is supposed to be a Real Estate Agency ... one day. So signing up is in order to insert an ad. Is this of importance ? Thanks for all your answers, I am still a bit puzzled. So many different opinions.

Comment: Ok with the idea of occupying less server-side ressources. But replacing the $_SESSION with a hidden variable would lead to having 2 $_POST, one with the user input, one with the solution. Would not this lead a to security issue ? Someone could change my form and falsificate the hidden field once for all, giving  a 100% guess mechanism to a bot. don't you think so ? Thanks

Comment: @SunnyOne, sure but you're already relying on bot-authors not customizing their bots to your captcha.

Comment: Ok with that. What about the solution of combining the storage of the right answer in a Session AND having a sleep() function of 1 second at the first request , 2 seconds at the 2nd, 4 seconds at the 3rd on so on ... ? Would it prevent the resources to be eaten up ? Thanks.

Comment: @SunnyOne, no.  That just ties up threads on your server too.